# Query sql result null when not found where in (array)

Tags: sql, join

car

| id | brand | available |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | toyota | yes |
| 2 | nissan | yes |
| 3 | masda | no |
| 4 | tesla | yes |

purchase

| id_car | date | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01 | $50 |
| 1 | 2020-02 | $52 |
| 2 | 2020-01 | $43 |
| 3 | 2020-01 | $35 |
| 3 | 2020-02 | $32 |
| 3 | 2020-03 | $15 |
| 4 | 2020-03 | $43 |

I need results like in the following table

| id | brand | available | date | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | toyota | yes | 2020-01 | $50 |
| 1 | toyota | yes | 2020-02 | $52 |
| 2 | nissan | yes | 2020-01 | $43 |
| 2 | nissan | yes | 2020-02 | null |
| 4 | tesla | yes | 2020-01 | null |
| 4 | tesla | yes | 2020-02 | null |

my query search must use availability and date(array)

```
select .....
join ....
where
car.available = 'yes'
and purchase.date in ('2020-01', '2020-02')
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've found it only the one that gives null doesn't exist, I want to return the null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a calendar table cross join approach here:

```sql
SELECT c.id, c.brand, 'yes' AS available, d.date, p.price
FROM (SELECT id, brand FROM car WHERE available = 'yes') c
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT date FROM purchase) d
LEFT JOIN purchase p
    ON p.id_car = c.id AND p.date = d.date
WHERE d.date IN ('2020-01', '2020-02')
ORDER BY c.id;
```

The idea is to generate two sets, one for all available car brands, and the other for all known available dates.  We then left join this intermediate table to the `purchase` table to get the output you want.

Comment: the date in the purchase table is just an example, actually it will be a lot of different dates and I want to search for a specific date using an array

Comment: I got it...in that case, just add a date restriction to the `WHERE` clause and it should work as you want.\